# Does Ron have Stockholm Syndrome in The Walking Dead?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, analysis, the-walking-dead

From re-watching, I started to think about Ron's psychology. Obviously, we all know that Ron hates Carl because of the whole Enid situation, and while some of that anger could have seeped into Rick, we start to notice him cracking before hand. When he began cracking, it was mainly after Pete slashes Deanna's husband's throat and then got his face blasted by Rick's revolver. Prior, we can see that he is all normal, and even being friendly and welcoming to Carl. Again, we can say that was before the Enid problem, but at the same time, his violent and abusive father was around, harming his family. Once Rick ends the problem, then we start to see Ron acting out. From this, I began to think, did Ron suffer from some sort of Stockholm Syndrome? I would like to hear more on what others hear. Of course, there are still some details that could go against this, and I am not bias, so here is the list:

- It is possible that Ron was not aware about the abuse, and/or that he did not get abused like his mother and brother. However, even when his mother tells him the truth, he ignores it. It wouldn't work to say that he did not love them, especially because he did cry when they got eaten.
- Aside from the Enid problem, while that and Pete's death affected him, there was also some buildup with Carl that did not involve either.
- His mind could have been distorted due to the cycle of violence.

Comment: From https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Ron_Anderson : "Ron is physically scarred from the abuse received from his violent father, Pete, as shown when his mother asks him to lift his right arm up above his head, a task Ron clearly cannot do."

Answer (score 2):

Clinically speaking, the answer can only be "No".  I say that because, from a clinical standpoint, Stockholm Syndrome is defined by these 4 characteristics:

- A hostage's development of positive feelings towards the captor
- No previous relationship between hostage and captor
- A refusal by hostages to cooperate with police and other government authorities
- A hostage's belief in the humanity of the captor, ceasing to perceive
  them as a threat, when the victim holds the same values as the
  aggressor.

Since Ron and Pete are related, this eliminates Ron from suffering from Stockholm Syndrome by clinical definition.  That's not to say that an abusive relationship doesn't exist, and tens of thousands of people exist in abusive relationships and never have the courage to leave them and even defend their abuser, but that's something different than Stockholm Syndrome.  It's probably best defined as Domestic Violence.